# Nullable references types and ToString() overload

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Please, note that this question is about the latest C# 8 [nullable-references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), I've enabled it in `csproj` file by the following `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` declaration.

Consider the following simple code

```cs
class SortedList<T> where T : struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable
{
    private Node? _node;
    private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    class Node
    {
        public Node(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public T Value { get; }
        public Node? Next { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    //rest of code, that isn't important
}
```

The line `return Value.ToString();` gives me a **CS8603 Possible null reference return** warning and my question actually why is it here?

I'm using the `where T : struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable` generic constraint to match a numeric types, `Value` is value type actually, not the reference one. There is also no overload of `ToString()` to any value type, the default [implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Int32.cs,8d6f2d8bc0589463,references) for `Int32` (for example) returns non-nullable `string`. MSDN [notes to inheritors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#notes-to-inheritors) is also saying that

> Your `ToString()` override should not return `Empty` or a `null` string.

Does the compiler complaining about some type, which can satisfy the generic constraint and return `null` from `ToString()`?

I can avoid the warning by making a return type nullable

```cs
public override string? ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString();
}
```

or by using the null-coalescing operator

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString() ?? "";
}
```

or by null-forgiving operator

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString()!;
}
```

But these options look like a tricks mostly, I'm looking for explanation of this behavior, why is there, by design or any other reasons were take place? Is there any ways to avoid the warning, except those above?

Btw, this option doesn't work, warning still in place

```cs
[return: MaybeNull]
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString();
}
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and VS 2019 16.4.2, but I don't think it's really important here.
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: The `ToString` shouldn't return a null string, return something meaningful.

Comment: Looks to be missing bit in Roslyn. Scroll down to _UPDATE 2019-10-08 (II)_: https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/non-nullable-references-in-dotnet-core/

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That's true, I've followed the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#notes-to-inheritors) guides for that.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Thanks for update, I didn't seen  this update and PR, actually it contradicts with the msdn link above

Comment: I remember seeing a discussion on whether `object.ToString()` should return `string?` or `string` (although I can't find it now). The conclusion was that although the guidance was to never return null, in fact a lot of code existed which *could* return null (including code which returned the result of calling `ToString()` on one of its members). Therefore making `object.ToString()` return `string` would introduce a lot of warnings into most people's code. To keep the noise down, they decided to document what actually happens in practice, but allow you to return `string` if you wanted.

Comment: @canton7 It sounds reasonable, but there is a little confusion between this [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#notes-to-inheritors) section and GitHub [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23510) for this functionality.

Comment: I think those are consistent. You *should not* return `null`. However, *in practice* `ToString` methods in the wild *do* return `null`, because some people don't follow the guidelines. By making `object.ToString` return `string?`, developers are alerted to the fact that a `ToString` method they call might in fact return `null`, and that they should guard against it (particularly if that method is defined in null-oblivious code). `ToString` overloads which follow the guidelines should return `string` not `string?`, and then users don't have to guard against `null`.

Comment: Note that when you generate an overload of `ToString` in Visual Studio, it generates a method with the signature `string` (not `string?`). So you're prompted not to return `null`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The signature for [`object.ToString()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Object.cs,39) is:

```
public virtual string? ToString()
```

That is, object's `ToString()` method is defined as returning a string which may be null.

Your overload of `Node.ToString()` tightens this requirement and promises to return a non-null string. This is fine. `Int32` does this, for example (as you noted).

*However*, your `Node.ToString()` method returns the value from `Value.ToString()`. We just saw that this `ToString` method (i.e. `object.ToString()`) might return `null`. Therefore the compiler's warning you that your `Node.ToString()` method might inadvertently return `null`, if `Value.ToString()` returns `null`.

---

This explains why you found that declaring `Node.ToString()` as:

```
public override string? ToString()
```

suppressed the warning: you're now declaring that your `Node.ToString()` method might return `null`, so it's not a problem if `Value.ToString()` returns `null` and you then return this value.

It also explains why writing `return Value.ToString() ?? "";` suppressed the warning: if `Value.ToString()` returned `null`, that code would ensure that `Node.ToString()` did not return `null`.

---

How best to fix this? You decide.

Do you *want* to promise that your `Node.ToString()` method never returns `null`? If so, you'll need to figure out what to do if `Value.ToString()` returns `null`.

Otherwise, it's probably best to follow the established pattern, and say that your `Node.ToString()` method might return `null`.

---

*Why* does `object.ToString()` return `string?`? See [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466) for a full discussion, but the gist is that there are `ToString` methods in the wild which *do* return `null`, because some people don't follow the guideline that you should never return `null` or an empty string.

1. If you are referencing a type which was built without nullable annotations, the fact that `object.ToString()` returns `string?` means that you'll be given a warning unless you check for `null`. This protects you from a badly-written `ToString` methods.
2. If you a referencing a type which was built *with* nullable annotations, then either:

   1. The author followed the guidelines, and declared their `ToString` method as returning `string`. In this case, the compiler assumes that you won't get `null`.
   2. The author explicitly did not follow the guidelines, and declared their `ToString` method as returning `string?`. In this case, you're forced to check for `null`.

Note that when you create an overload of `ToString` in Visual Studio, the generated method returns `string` (even if the method being overloaded returns `string?`). This prompts you to follow the guidelines.

The only annoyance here is when you're dealing with a generic type, or a type which has been cast to `object`. In this case, the compiler doesn't know whether the object's `ToString` method is following the guidelines or not. Because `object.ToString` returns `string?`, the compiler assumes the worst. You can override this assumption if you wish with the null-forgiving operator `!`.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, that makes sense, I haven't consider `object.ToString()` here. But why `[return: MaybeNull]` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski `MaybeNull` only affects the *contract* of the method -- it affects other code which calls the method, but does not affect code inside the method. [Compare here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgCIEsCGBzAdgewGcAXdAY0OQGF9gBTAQV0wBsBPQ9QgbgFgAoAMS4ArixaYARizpw6zaXQFQAzAgBMcKnADeAuAYRqoAFjgBZABQBKXfsMOAYvnw3kAFXwBlYgCd0uNg2fPwODgBCmL5unj7+gcH2BgC+SXBpANpQAOwgFphsknQAcmIsALppqgiI8M6utgC8AHxwouIhDlXGtXCR0U2t7SwhyUA==)