# Why does the signature of object.ToString state that it can return a null value

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I encountered this while enabling the nullable feature in our projects.

In Net 5.0 the signature for [`object.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0) is

```
public virtual string? ToString ();
```

Why is that?
The [notes to Inheritors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#notes-to-inheritors) even state

> Your ToString() override should not return Empty or a null string.

so why does the signature state that it can? I could not find any info on that.

But my ideas are

- Backwards comparability for those people who didn't read the note mentioned above and return null from their ToString method.
- To let the people who read the mentioned note ignore it

But since we want to treat the warnings that come with the nullable feature as errors now we have to add `!` or a null check everywhere we use `ToString`.

Is there any other good reason why the signature is as it is?

Comment: "*Backwards comparability for those people who didn't read the note mentioned above and return null from their ToString method.*" -- it's exactly this: there are real-world ToString implementations out there that return `null`. You'll notice that if you write your own ToString method in VS, the return type defaults to `string` not `string?` however -- this is to encourage you to follow the guidelines. If you use a type which defines its own `ToString` method and uses NRTs, it will probably also return `string`, and you won't need to nullcheck it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable references types and ToString() overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581046/nullable-references-types-and-tostring-overload)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Backwards comparability for those people who didn't read the note mentioned above and return null from their ToString method.

It's exactly this: there are real-world ToString implementations out there that return `null`. See [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466) for full details.

You'll notice that if you write your own ToString method in VS, the return type defaults to `string` not `string?` however -- this is to encourage you to follow the guidelines. If you use a type which defines its own `ToString` method and uses NRTs, it will probably also return `string`, and you won't need to nullcheck it.

The fact that `object.ToString()` returns `string?` is only relevant:

1. When you've cast an object to `object`, and the compiler doesn't know whether its overridden `ToString` method actually returns `string?` or `string`
2. When you're using an unconstrained generic type, for the same reason

```
C c = new C();
string s1 = c.ToString(); // No warning

object o = c;
string s2 = o.ToString(); // Warning

public class C
{
    public override string ToString() => "";
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEA3GUCWAZgJ5oAmIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAUGwMQB2ArgDZ8AhsD4wABDC7DRbNgGExYMQF4xXGAHcxcgBQBKANxtajAAxiAzoxWKAdABUIAZQwEuAc30GxAeh9iAOQgxDUEoLnwPWVYIYAArGDAMMWDVMCNWE3MLehsIB2dXSM9DX38AdTCIqPZMgGYxBm02AG82MQ7GhohcKAIycSyxRxc3EpUAPjEAImmMgF8gA==)